# How to deal with nullable values in Iterator implementation in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, linked-list

So I was following the Algorithms book by Sedgewick and trying to translate the implementations from Java to Kotlin and when I tried to implement one Iterator for the `Bag` data structure (that's essentially a one-way linked list), I got stuck with nullability issues and thread safety in Kotlin.

The implementation in java from the book is done this way:

```
public class Bag<Item> {
   private Node first;

   private class Node {
       Item item;
       Node next;
   }

   /* some methods */

   private class Iterator<Item> {
      private Node current = first;

      public boolean hasNext() { current != null; }

      public Item next() {
          if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
          Item item = current.item;
          current = current.next;
          return item;
      }
   }
}
```

which I tried to implement in Kotlin like this:

```
class Bag<Item> : Iterable<Item> {
   private inner class Node(val item: Item, val next: Node?)

   private var first : Node? = null

   /* Some methods */

   override fun iterator() = object : Iterator<Item> {
      private var current : Bag<Item>.Node? = first

      override fun hasNext() : Boolean = current != null

      override fun next() : Item {
         if (current == null) throw NoSuchElementException()

         val item = current.item
         current = current.next
         return item
      }
   }
}
```

But I got the following error:

> Smart cast to 'Bag.Node' is impossible, because 'current' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

I understand this is due to race condition between checking if the variable is null and actually accessing the variable attributes, since the variable could be set to null by other threads. After some time I arrived into the following implementation:

```
override fun iterator() = object : Iterator<Item> {
   private var current : Bag<Item>.Node? = first

   override fun hasNext() : Boolean = current != null

   override fun next() : Item {
      current?.let {
         val item = it.item
         current = it.next
         return item
      } ?: throw NoSuchElementException()
   }
}
```

And the compiler thought this was fine. But I still have some doubts. Which leads to my questions:

**1) Is the assignment `current = it.next` thread safe or should I assign to the implicit `it` instead?**

**2) Is there a idiomatic Kotlin way of implementing an iterator of non-nullable type that ends with a null value? (meaning that all values in it are non-null except for the ending condition)**

Comment: I will suggest you to use your own iterator over there, (you can handle those nulled values ) predefined iterator function may not have thread safe mechanism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the assignment current = it.next thread safe

It is not thread safe.

Imagine a list of integers and two threads `A` and `B` who want to use iterator instance `I`.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5            A: item=1, next=(2)
^                                A: item=1, next=(2)
I
```

Both threads begin to iterate. Both path inside `current?.let`. Both read current item (`val item = it.item`) and got `item=1, next=(2)`. Then, first thread `A` is frozen and second thread `B` advances the iterator, let's say, by three items forward:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5            A: item=1, next=(2)
               ^                 B: item=4, next=(5)
               I
```

Now `B` enters `let` and reads next `item`: `item=4, next=(5)`. Remember that `A` is still in his loop and it's `item` is `item=1, next=(2)`. If `B` is now frozen and `A` advances one line of code (`current = it.next`) then things are broken: `current` is a shared state (as it is stored in the iterator) and, thus, `B` will see the change as well. On the next iteration in `B` it will be "thrown back" to the item #2. Nothing bad will happen and the program will not fail, but most probably that is not the behavior you need.

Even more: for the described reasons iterators are not meant to be thread-safe and every thread should have it's own, independent one. Things become more interesting with iterators that change a collection (insertions / deletions), but it's another story as it is about the collection, not about the iterator.

> Should I assign to the implicit it instead?

You cannot assign to it, as it is a function parameter and it is passed by value, and, thus, cannot be changed. The compiler will ban the assignment with a message like "Val cannot be reassigned"

> Is there a idiomatic Kotlin way of implementing an iterator of non-nullable type that ends with a null value?

I'd say: yes. You could potentially use [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) to designate different types of nodes like:

```
sealed class Node<out T>;

object Empty : Node<Nothing>();

data class Full<T>(val item: T, val next: Node<T>) : Node<T>();

class Bag<T>(private val first: Node<T>) : Iterable<T> {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<T> = object : Iterator<T> {
        private var current = first

        override fun hasNext() = current !is Empty

        override fun next() = when (val c = current) {
            Empty -> throw IllegalStateException()
            is Full -> {
                current = c.next
                c.item
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val bag = Bag(Full(1, Full(2, Full(3, Empty))))

    bag.forEach(::println)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised to not see this method listed, which has been available since Kotlin 1.3. You can use the `iterator {}` helper in conjunction with `yield()` to easily build an iterator that handles `null` effectively.

For example, in a LinkedList:

```kotlin
class NamedLinkedListNode(
    val name: String,
    val next: NamedLinkedListNode?
) : Iterable<String> {
    override fun iterator() = iterator {
        var node: NamedLinkedListNode? = this@NamedLinkedListNode
        while (node != null) {
            yield(node.name)
            node = node.next
        }
    }
}
```